# Java 1.7, Group list items in an arraylist and aggregate by spesific attribute from the arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

[image: group list items and aggregate by an attribute]

In the picture above, I have an arraylist in type T,

I want to group list items by an attribute, meanwhile aggreate another attribute, and make a new arraylist from the result.
Thanks for any help... 
Edit: The picture link is dead, but I remember trying to explain what I need with a sketch more than a piece of code. And I was such a newbie to java back then that I coudn't do a simple foreach loop in a List I'd appreciate if downvoters took it back because Sacoverflow says I might be blocked for asking questions...

Comment: What's the problem? What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried mapping but I couldn't get the aggregated results, I can't get the right loop to iterate over the arraylist and create the logic I need,
I'm basically a newbie, sorry..

Comment: Edit your question and include the code you tried.  Include the code as text, not as a picture.

Comment: Please read [mcve] - and then add code/problem descriptions to you questions. And please: dont use screen shots for information that could easily be written down as pure text!

Comment: I tried but couldn't get the code block working, it doesn't allow me to submit my edit. Again, sorry I've know stackoverflow for long, but asked very few questions, I'm not familiar with the concept. apologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with simple `for` loop involving a `List` and a `Map`, e.g.:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
for(T t : list) {
    if(map.containsKey(t.attr1)) {
        map.put(t.attr1, map.get(t.attr1) + t.attr2);
    }else {
        map.put(t.attr1, t.attr2);
    }
}
System.out.println(map);
```

Comment: Thank you, this does exactly what I want. I was doing  "map.get(t.attr1) + t.attr2" part wrong